# iOS: When to Use Which Code Signing Identity in The Build Configuration?

Tags: ios, testing, code-signing, buildconfiguration

I am never very clear regarding to which Code Signing Identity I should use in the Build Configuration concerning which scenario, and would love if someone can explain it in the most simple way.

This is what I know:

1. I create in the Provisioning Portal and implement in my apps both a Development Profile and a Distribution Profile.
   [image: Provision Portal - creating the profiles]
2. Then I assign the **Project >> Build Settings >> Code Signing** according to the different profiles:
   [image: Code Signing]

Here is the first question: **What is the difference between *Release* and *Distribution*? Which one should be connected to the Developer profile and which one should be connected to the Distribution profile?**

3. Now, if I understand correctly, I'm supposed to set the "Scheme" before I run the app:
   [image]

There are 5 different steps in which I'm required to define the Build Configuration by selecting one of the **Code Signing Identity**:

[image]   [image]

Here is the BIG QUESTION... **In which scenario I should select which Code Signing Identity?**

I always run the app on the same 2 devices: my iPhone and my iPad; both are defined in the Provisioning Portal and set into the profiles.
I only want to make sure I run it OK for testing on Simulator and on Device and later on to build the app for uploading to App Store.

Any assistance / direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, the standard Apple templates only create Debug and Release configurations.  Distribution seems to be redundant with Release.

Debug is the configuration used when you are actually working on the code, and Release is used when you archive it for other people to install.  You should use your developer profile for Debug and your distribution profile for Release.

You should also probably use your distribution profile for distribution, but you should really check with whoever created that configuration to see what its purpose is first.

Comment: Thanks Jim - just to make sure I got it - When I run the app on my test device (not the simulator), I should have "Debug" set in all the Build Configuration fields, right? And only when I run it for Archive so I can upload the file to App Store I should change all the Build Configuration fields to "Release". Did I get it right?

Comment: You shouldn't have to manually choose a configuration.  That what the schemes handle.  If you edit the scheme you are working on, you'll see *Run* and *Archive* (among others) in the left-hand pane.  If you select *Run*, you should see that the build configuration is set to Debug.  If you select *Archive*, you should see that the build configuration is set to Release.

Comment: This is how Xcode knows which build configuration it should use when it is building the app.  When you are developing the app and you run it, it will use the settings in the scheme for *Run*, and when you archive it for ad hoc distribution or App Store submission, it will use the settings in the scheme for *Archive*.